# How to clear listbox entries when pressing a button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listboxitem

I am using a Listbox in order to display some text when I press a button. However, when I press this button again to re-display, it just puts the text below the original text in the `listbox`. I have searched for ways to fix this problem but I cannot seem to find one that works for my specific program. The point of my program is to check a password entered by a user.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#Imports
from tkinter import *
from random import *
import string

#Root And GUI Title
root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Password Checker")

#Top Frame
topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.grid(row=0)

#Bottom Frame And Geometry And Check Labels
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.grid(row=10)
root.geometry("1000x1000")
checkLabel = Label(root)
checkCap = Label(root)
checkLow = Label(root)
checkSymb = Label(root)
checkDig = Label(root)

listbox = Listbox(root)
listbox.grid(row=6, column=1)


#Checker Function 
def checker():
    if len(passEntry.get()) < 8 or len(passEntry.get()) > 24:
        listbox.insert(END, "Invalid Length")
        listbox.grid(row=1, column=1)

    if len(passEntry.get()) >= 8 and len(passEntry.get()) <= 24:
        #checkLabel.config(text="Valid Length")
        #checkLabel.grid(row=10, column = 1)
        listbox.insert(END, "Valid Length")


    cap = re.search("[A-Z]", passEntry.get())
    if cap:
        #checkCap.config(text="Okay Capitals")
        #checkCap.grid(row=11, column = 1)
        listbox.insert(END, "Okay Capitals")
    else:
        #checkCap.config(text="No Capitals")
        #checkCap.grid(row=11, column = 1)
        listbox.insert(END, "No Capitals")
    low = re.search("[a-z]", passEntry.get())
    if low:
        #checkLow.config(text="Okay Lowercase")
        #checkLow.grid(row=12, column = 1)
        listbox.insert(END, "Okay Lowercase")
    else:
        #checkLow.config(text="No Lowercase")
        #checkLow.grid(row=12, column = 1)
        listbox.insert(END, "No Lowercase")
    symb = re.search("[!£$%^&*()]", passEntry.get())
    if symb:
        #checkSymb.config(text="Okay Symbols")
        #checkSymb.grid(row=13, column= 1)
        listbox.insert(END, "Okay Symbols")
    else:
        #checkSymb.config(text="No Symbols")
        #checkSymb.grid(row=13, column = 1)
        listbox.insert(END, "No Symbols")
    dig = re.search("[0-9]", passEntry.get())
    if dig:
        #checkDig.config(text="Okay Digits")
        #checkDig.grid(row=14, column = 1)
        listbox.insert(END, "Okay Digits")
    else:
        #checkDig.config(text="No Digits")
        #checkDig.grid(row=14, column = 1)
        global noDigits
        noDigits = listbox.insert(END, "No Digits")


#Password Entry
passEntryLabel = Label(root, text="Password")
passEntryLabel.grid(row=0, column=3)
passEntry = Entry(root)
PAR = passEntry.get()
passEntry.grid(row=0, column=4)
checkButton = Button(root, text="Check Password", command=checker)
checkButton.grid(row=0, column=7)
#Mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

When I enter a first password:
[First Password Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzxGj.png)

When I enter a second password:
[Second Password Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M7p5.png)

After entering the second password it just puts the next set of checks below the old ones, so how would I make it that the old set gets deleted when entering the second password? Thanks.

Comment: You have posted a lot of irrelevant code. Can you condense it down to a [mcve]. Also, show where you've tried using the documented `delete` method to clear the entry and/or listbox.

Comment: Please include python tag unless the question is exclusively about python 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the [document](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/listbox.htm#M29)ed:

```
listbox.delete('0', 'end')
```

in order to [`delete`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.delete-method) all entries in `listbox` to, -- the method that updates your [Listbox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm), `checker` as the first line.